# Why is only a single underwater robotic submarine Bluefin-21 being deployed in the search for MH370?

Tags: search-and-rescue, mh370-incident

As my question states, why is only a single Bluefin-21 being deployed underwater to scan the seabed with an area of around 40 square miles?

Why aren't multiple Bluefin-21's getting deployed when deploying multiple machines would make the search faster when everything here is a very time consuming process?

Comment: cost and availability, it is very expensive to deploy the thing

Comment: @ratchetfreak I would say only availability. If you deploy 1 for 10 days or 10 for 1 day, the cost remains unchanged

Comment: `If you deploy 1 for 10 days or 10 for 1 day, the cost remains unchanged` very nice point.

Comment: @Federico that assumes no other fixed costs, getting the ship supporting ship out there takes fuel and when it is there it can remain there for a few weeks and deploy several days in a row

Comment: @ratchetfreak ship fuel is not `very expensive` though (and now you are assuming that you need one support ship per bluefin)

Comment: @fooot we go back to the initial point: 1 AUV per 10 days cost the same as 10 AUVs per 1 day

Comment: Would you rather fly 10 AUVs to Australia, then fly them back the next day, or just fly 1 down there and let it stay a while? Shipping isn't cheap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Bluefin-21

> Why not multiple Bluefin-21's

There is only one Bluefin-21.

The other Bluefins 12S, 12D, 9M etc are mostly for shallow water work.

### Other AUVs

The Bluefin-21 is not the only commercial Autonomous Underwater Vehicle (AUV) equipped with side-scan sonar.

The US Navy has spent $20M on an order for eight [Knifefish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knifefish_%28robot%29) (a Bluefin-21 derivative) but these are not due to enter active service until 2017. They are for mine-detection and so (I surmise) may not be well suited to deep-ocean usage.

The Royal Navy has a number of REMUS 600 AUVs but these are not designed for use deeper than 600M

It may be that most existing AUVs equipped with side-scan-sonar are not capable of deep-ocean use.

Comment: Judging from the fact that they are replacing dolphins and operating from Littoral Combat Ships, I would say they are not designed for deep-water use.

Answer (score 1):

Most of capable AUVs belong to offshore drilling companies like Chevron and Royal Dutch Shell. Some are also operated by deep sea cable companies.

The various armed forces operate only a handful of these AUVs, and because they are quite expensive, not many marine science institutes have them.